# How to eliminate the Miller effect on BJT BC547?

Tags: bjt

[image]

I have an application:

- The input in a 3V train pulse @ 100Khz
- I need an Ic to be 10mA for the LEF of the optocoupler.

I am using BC547C:

- Input Capacitance= 9pF
- Current Gain Bandwidth Product(hFE)=400.

The problem is the Miller effect, it will make (Rb+CM) act as a low pass filer at10Khz if m calculation is right.
[Miller effect info](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits_Audio_Amp/Miller_Effect/Miller_Effect.htm)

How can I solve this problem 
Are their another way to get my desire output ?

Is this circuit with mosfet will work ?
I could change the LM231 output  from 5V to 15V.
[image]

The lm231 circuit I used is at page 10 in this [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm231.pdf)

Comment: A desired output of 10mA? What precisely does this mean? You show "Vout" in your picture. Also, why is your base resistor 160 kohms? Please justify.

Comment: 1) Cascode. 2) (simpler) a compensating capacitor across Rb. Calculate its value and check square wave response in simulator.

Comment: @Andyaka,  I have an optocoupler, I update the schematic, it will be clear know.

Comment: @BrianDrummond could you help my more, how I calculate the compensating capacitor across Rb ?

Comment: If the input is a 5V signal, why don't you connect the transistor as an emitter follower and lose the base resistor entirely? There's not too much point in speeding it up too much, the 4N25 will be really really slow if you're using a simple load.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I will try it. I read that emitter follower need a little current from the input?. My input is form a voltage to frequency converter IC, So it is only voltage.---http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-follower.html

Comment: The current required is Iled/hFE, so it will draw very little current (< 0.1mA). Unlike the common source circuit, no current is wasted, only the required amount is drawn from the source.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so it will draw a 25uA, but as I mention , my input is coming form a IC "LM231", does an IC output current (I am new to electonics)

Comment: The LM231 cannot source any current- it's an open-collector output that can sink a few mA. See my answer below.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/136944/17429

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you want to drive an opto-isolator with an LM231 output.

The [LM231](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm231.pdf) has an open-collector output and cannot source current- so it won't work with your circuit as shown. It doesn't have a quite enough current capability to be guaranteed to drive the 7mA you've chosen for the opto.

[image]

Possible solutions include:

1. Use a better (higher CTR) opto-isolator and drive it with 5mA. Then you need only connect the optoisolator LED to Vcc with a series resistor.
2. Use a PNP emitter follower as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwM5sx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As I mentioned in my comments, the [4N25](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0010/S_110_4N25(26).pdf) with a suitable load resistor (something like 7-10K) will be very slow and may not work up to 10kHz.

[image]

Edit: Your modified circuit will work, however use a 2N7000 or similar small MOSFET rather than an IRFB4310, use 470 ohms rather than 2K, and connect a 2K from the gate to Vcc (pullup resistor).

Comment: @ thanks, I am short of component know, I have to work with what I have, is it okay if I use a power MOSFET as a switch ? I put a schismatic,Is it Ok or I will face some limitations?

Comment: You can use a small n-channel MOSFET (eg. 2N7000) with a pullup resistor like 2K (don't use a source follower- use common source). Whatever you make (within reason) will be much faster than the 4N25. Don't use a big power MOSFET.

Comment: "Whatever you make (within reason) will be much faster than the 4N25." I didnt understand ? , I must use 4N25, and I cannot order a new IC, I need to finishit as soon as posible, thanks alot sir.

Comment: Sir,About (the 2K pullup resistor) I already have a 10K from Vcc to pin3 of lm231 as its in the recommended datasheet, I will put the circuit I am using for lm231 up.

Answer (score 1):

First off, to get 10mA through the opto-coupler LED you need to reduce the value of RLed. The LED drops about 1.2V, so RLed should be 380 Ohms or less.

Secondly, at 160k Rb may not provide enough Base current to get a reliable 10mA at the Collector. Using a much lower value would ensure that the transistor turns on fully, and also reduce Miller effect.

You could connect the LM231's output directly to the Base of the transistor, then it will turn off much faster because the comparator is providing a low resistance path to discharge the miller capacitance. With a 10k pullup resistor you should get rise and fall times of less than 200ns at the LED.

The 4N25 has inherently slow response, so your 100kHz square wave input will come out looking (at best) more like a triangle wave. This may be OK if you just want to get some kind of pulse through and aren't worried about distortion.

Comment: I need to convert the voltage to frequency(Lm231) enter the 4N25, and then convert it back using lm2907. The reason I was planing to get this scale (100Hz output 10V) is that the lm2907 has 7% error at 10V: if I enter a 100Hz I get a 1V , and if I enter a 1Khz I get a 9.3V... So I change the timing capacitor from 103 to 101, and eliminate the error get. but I have two new problem, the miller effect and the 4N25 slow response. I think I will try to find the reason behind the nonlinear of lm2907.

Comment: The LM2907 can take practically any waveform, so it should work with the 4N25 up to 100kHz. For maximum signal amplitude from the 4N25, choose a load resistor that matches the expected output current, eg. 470 Ohms at 5V (assumes 100% CTR).

Comment: another question, I input a 10V AC into LM231 , So the input to LM2907 is variable frequency , But I notice that the LM2907 have a slow response! .. I use MyDAQ to generate the 10VAC and observe the output from LM2907. What may speed up the response ?

Comment: You can reduce the values of the charge pump capacitors (on pins 2 and 3) and also reduce the resistance on pin 3. Read the LM2907 datasheet page 8 to get formula and recommended limits.